# How can i remove old input for specific select option with jquery?

Tags: jquery, input, html-select

When I select an option it shows specific inputs but when I want to change the select to another option, I can show another specific inputs but cant remove old inputs. How can i do it?

The JS shows new inputs for specific select option but cant remove old inputs

```js
$('#main-div').children(':not(#device,#ydm)').hide(); //ilk olaraq hamisini gizle

$("#device").change(function() {
  var value = $('#device').find(":selected").text().trim();
  var dispensor = "Dispensor";
  // console.log(input);
  if (value == dispensor) {
    //$('input:not(#count,#ydm,#inventory_number)').slideToggle( "slow");
    //$('#main-div').children(':not(#count,#form,#device,#model,#ydm,#inventory_number)').slideToggle();
    $('#main-div').children().filter('#count,#form,#device,#model,#ydm,#inventory_number').show(700);
  }

  // Animation complete.);
  var tank = "Tank";
  if (value == tank) {
    // $('#main-div').children(':not(#count,#ydm,#capacity,#form,#device)').slideToggle();
    $('#main-div').children().filter('#count,#ydm,#capacity,#form,#device').show(900);
    // Animation complete.);
  }

  var sampleCup = "SampleCup";
  if (value == sampleCup) {
    //$('#main-div').children(':not(#count,#ydm,#factory_number,#form,#device)').slideToggle();
    $('#main-div').children().filter('#count,#ydm,#factory_number,#form,#device').show(900);
    // Animation complete.);
  }

  var Metroshtok = "Metroshtok";
  if (value == Metroshtok) {
    // $('#main-div').children(':not(#count,#ydm,#form,#device)').slideToggle();
    $('#main-div').children().filter('#count,#ydm,#form,#device').show(900);
    // Animation complete.);
  }

  var Computer = "Computer";
  if (value == Computer) {
    //$('#main-div').children(':not(#count,#model,#inventory_number,#ydm,#form,#device)').slideToggle();
    $('#main-div').children().filter('#count,#model,#inventory_number,#ydm,#form,#device').show(900);
    // Animation complete.);
  }

  var Ibm = "IBM";
  if (value == Ibm) {
    //$('#main-div').children(':not(#count,#factory_number,#ydm,#form,#device)').slideToggle();
    $('#main-div').children().filter('#count,#factory_number,#ydm,#form,#device').show(900);
    // Animation complete.);
  }
  
  var Router = "Router";
  if (value == Router) {
    //$('#main-div').children(':not(#count,#model,#ydm,#form,#device)').slideToggle();
    $('#main-div').children().filter('#count,#model,#ydm,#form,#device').show(900);
    // Animation complete.);
  }

  var Switchs = "Switchs";
  if (value == Switchs) {
    //$('#main-div').children(':not(#count,#model,#ydm,#form,#device)').slideToggle();
    $('#main-div').children().filter('#count,#model,#ydm,#form,#device').show(900);
    // Animation complete.);
  }

  var Ip = "Ip";
  if (value == Ip) {
    //$('#main-div').children(':not(#ip,#ydm,#form,#device)').slideToggle();
    $('#main-div').children().filter('#ip,#ydm,#form,#device').show(900);
    // Animation complete.);
  }

  var Location = "Locations";
  if (value == Location) {
    //$('#main-div').children(':not(#location,#ydm,#form,#device)').slideToggle();
    $('#main-div').children().filter('#location,#ydm,#form,#device').show(900);
    // Animation complete.);
  }

  var DataCard = "DataCard";
  if (value == DataCard) {
    //$('#main-div').children(':not(#provider,#brx_number,#speed_limit,#ydm,#form,#device)').slideToggle();
    $('#main-div').children().filter('#provider,#brx_number,#speed_limit,#ydm,#form,#device').show(900);
    // Animation complete.);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-div" class="field">
  <div id="device" class="field">
    <label class="label">Avadanlıq</label>
    <div class="control">
      <div class="select">
        <select id="device" name="device">
          <option>Avadanlıq seç</option>
          @foreach($devices as $device)
            <option selected; value="">{{$device->name}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ydm" class="field">
    <label id="ydmLabel" class="label">Əlavə olunacağı Ydm</label>
    <div class="control">
      <div class="select">
        <select id="ydm" name="ydm">
          <option selected>Ydm seç</option>
          <option></option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="model" class="control">
    <label id="model" class="label">Modeli</label>
    <input class="input" name="model" type="text" placeholder="Avadanlığın modeli">
  </div>
  <div id="count" class="field">
    <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
      <label id="count" class="label">Sayı</label>
      <input id="count" class="input is-success" type="text" name="count" placeholder="Sayı" value="">
      <span class="icon is-small is-left">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="inventory_number" class="field">
    <label id="inventory_number" class="label">İnventar nömrəsi</label>
    <input id="inventory_number" class="input is-danger" name="inventory_number" type="text" placeholder="İnventar nömrəsi" value="">
  </div>
  <div id="factory_number" class="field">
    <label class="label">Zavod nömrəsi</label>
    <input class="input is-danger" name="factory_number" id="factory_number" type="text" placeholder="Zavod nömrəsi" value="">
  </div>
  <div id="capacity" class="field">
    <label class="label">Tutumu</label>
    <input class="input is-danger" id="capacity" name="capacity" type="text" placeholder="Tutumu" value="">
  </div>
  <div id="ip" class="field">
    <label class="label">IP Adresi</label>
    <input class="input is-danger" id="ip" name="capacity" type="text" placeholder="IP Adresi" value="">
  </div>
  <div id="speed_limit" class="field">
    <label class="label">Sürət limiti</label>
    <input class="input is-danger" name="speed_limit" id="speed_limit" type="text" placeholder="Sürət limiti" value="">
  </div>
  <div id="provider" class="field">
    <label class="label">Provayderi</label>
    <input class="input is-danger" type="text" id="provider" name="provider" placeholder="Provayderi" value="">
  </div>
  <div id="brx_number" class="field">
    <label class="label">Brx nömrəsi</label>
    <input class="input is-danger" type="text" name="brx_number" id="brx_number" placeholder="Brx nömrəsi" value="">
  </div>
  <div id="location" class="field">
    <label class="label">Ünvan əlavə et</label>
    <input class="input is-danger" type="url" name="location" id="location" placeholder="Ydm-ə ünvan əlavə et" value="">
  </div>
  <div id="form" class="field is-grouped">
    <div class="control">
      <button type="submit" class="button is-link">Əlavə et</button>
    </div>
    <div class="control">
      <button class="button is-link is-light">İmtina et</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```